# Are random effect models same as Bayesian versions of fixed effect models?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, random-effects-model

Are random effect models same as Bayesian version of fixed effect models, in the sense that the parameters or coefficients are random variables?

For example, is the [Bayesian linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression) model viewed as a random effect model?

Comment: Well, no, at least not for an *ordinary* Bayesian linear regression. A random effects model has a "different" parameter or parameters (say, a different intercept) for each subject, drawn from a population distribution of parameters. An ordinary Bayesian linear regression has a 'random' parameter in the sense that the parameter has a distribution, but it is common to all the subjects. On the other hand, a particular kind of Bayesian *hierarchical* regression model is very similar to a random effects model and is often treated as the 'Bayesian' version of it.

Comment: @Glen_b:Thanks! "A random effects model has a "different" parameter or parameters (say, a different intercept) for each subject, drawn from a population distribution of parameters." I don't understand what is "drawn from a population distribution of parameters" and how that is like? Could you explain more specifically? (I think math formulation will make it clear)

Comment: [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model#Simple_example) or Eqn 1 of page 2 [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered in comments:

Well, no, at least not for an ordinary Bayesian linear regression. A random effects model has a "different" parameter or parameters (say, a different intercept) for each subject, drawn from a population distribution of parameters. An ordinary Bayesian linear regression has a 'random' parameter in the sense that the parameter has a distribution, but it is common to all the subjects. On the other hand, a particular kind of Bayesian hierarchical regression model is very similar to a random effects model and is often treated as the 'Bayesian' version of it. – Glen_b

See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model#Simple_example